# Как в ymaps api просчитать периметр многоугольника (polygon)?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Есть задача:
пользователь рисует многоугольник (Polygon).
Необходимо просчитать периметр этого многоугольника.

Нашел только расчет площади, как найти периметр, имея только координаты многоугольника?

Comment: сложить стороны многоугольника, очевидно же)

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin как получить длины сторон?

Comment: по формуле расстояния между двумя точками

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin яндекс карты отдают только координаты точек.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать метод [distance](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/archive/doc/jsapi/1.x/ref/reference/geocoordsystem.html#method_detail__distance). Он возвращает расстояние между точками в метрах.